# key values from an NSDictionary formatting with "()"

Tags: iphone, nsstring, nsarray, nsdictionary

I'm trying to pull two values from this Dictionary, But the values I'm getting have "()" around them. Any Ideas what is causing this?

Here is the ServerOutput:

```
{"Rows":[{"userid":"1","location":"beach"}]}
```

Dictionary after JSON:

```
 {
    Rows =     (
            {
        location = beach;
        userid = 1;
    }
);
}
```

This is what I'm getting:

```
location : (
    beach
  )
user Id : (
    1
  )
```

Both the userid and the location key values have the "()". Here is the code. Thanks a lot.

```
    NSString *serverOutput= [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


if(serverOutput > 1){

       SBJSON *jsonFF = [[SBJSON new] autorelease];
       NSError *error3 = nil;
       NSDictionary *useridDict= [jsonFF objectWithString:serverOutput error:&error3];

       NSLog(@"useridDict: %@",useridDict);

    idreturn = [[useridDict valueForKey:@"Rows"] valueForKey:@"userid"];

    locationreturn = [[useridDict valueForKey:@"Rows"] valueForKey:@"location"];

    NSLog(@" user Id : %@", idreturn);
    NSLog(@" location : %@", locationreturn);
```

Comment: How is locationreturn declared?  Is it an NSArray?

Comment: the idreturn and locationreturns are NSStrings. Thanks

Comment: It seems like it's deciding the values as arrays, though I'm not sure why.

Comment: @Wevah Thanks, I set the returns to Arrays and am now using: NSString * idreturnst = [idreturn objectAtIndex:0]; to get value out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to clarify what is going on. When parsing JSON {} gets returned as a dictionary and [] gets retured as an array. So we have `useridDict` an `NSDictionary` containing the parsed data.

'useridDict' has one key `Rows` which returns an `NSArray`.

```
NSArray *useridArray = [useridDict objectForKey:@"Rows"];
```

Our `useridArray` has one element, an `NSDictionary`

```
NSDictionary *dict = [useridArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

This `dict` contains the two keys: `location` and `userid`

```
NSString *location = [dict objectForKey:@"location"];
NSInteger userid = [[dict objectForKey:@"userid"] intValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this.

```
idreturn = [[[useridDict valueForKey:@"Rows"] objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"userid"];

locationreturn = [[[useridDict valueForKey:@"Rows"] objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"location"];
```